# Can i run the Android emulator and Windows Phone emulator at the same time?

Tags: android-emulator, windows-phone-emulator

I have a little annoyance in regards to emulators with Xamarin. I can't run the Android and Windows Phone emulators at the same time.

If I turn Hyper-V on, I can run the Windows Phone emulator, then I have to turn it off for Android (this requires a restart of the machine each time).

Is there any simple way around this, or will I just have to live with it?

Thanks

Comment: I have launched through eclipse(when wp emulator is running), but i was not using xamarin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Visual Studio 2015 ([Preview](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs) or [CTP 6](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/visual-studio-2015-ctp-vs)) and install the [Visual Studio Emulator for Android](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studio-s-emulator-for-android.aspx). It will appear in your debug dropdown, and it's a Hyper-V emulator so it will run side-by-side with the Windows Phone emulator.